# Remove White Space in Virtuemart 'Featured Products' Module

Tags: html, joomla, joomla1.5, virtuemart, joomla-module

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to get rid of the whitespace. I really don't know what I'm doing wrong and I don't know enough about html to know if that's the problem.

*Screenshots attached:*

**1)** If I leave the code as is, my images overlap with the module directly below.
[image: Original code]

[image: Original code with highlights]

**2)** If I modify the code to make the table cell height 400px, It creates a large amount of white space. 
[image: Modified code height=400px]

[image: Modified code height=400px with highlights]

**3)** If I modify the code to make the table cell height 1-399px, It creates either too much white space or an overlap.

**MODIFIED CODE** (*NOTE: I'm using the "horizontal" display style*):

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tr>
    <span style="color:green"><b>> <b></span>Click here to <a href="http://localhost/joomlawebsite/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=52"><span style="color:blue"><b>view all featured products</b></span></a>.
</tr>
<?php
$i = 0;
while($db->next_record() ){
    if ($i%2)
    $sectioncolor = "sectiontableentry2";
    else
    $sectioncolor = "sectiontableentry1";

    if( $display_style == "vertical" ) {
    ?>
        <tr align="center" class="<?php echo $sectioncolor ?>">
            <td width="<?php echo $width ?>%">
                <?php 
                $ps_product->show_snapshot($db->f("product_sku"), $show_price, $show_addtocart);
                ?><br />
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    }
    elseif( $display_style== "horizontal" ) {
        if( $i == 0 )
        echo "<tr>\n";
        echo "<td height=\"400px\" width=\"$width%\" align=\"center\">";
        $ps_product->show_snapshot($db->f("product_sku"), $show_price, $show_addtocart);
        echo "</td>\n";
        if( ($i+1) == $db->num_rows() )
        echo "</tr>\n";
    }
    elseif( $display_style== "table" ) {
        if( $i == 0 )
        echo "<tr>\n";
        echo "<td width=\"$width%\" align=\"center\">";
        $ps_product->show_snapshot($db->f("product_sku"), $show_price, $show_addtocart);
        echo "</td>\n";
        if ( ($i+1) % $products_per_row == 0)
        echo "</tr><tr>\n";
        if( ($i+1) == $max_items )
        echo "</tr>\n";
    }
    $i++;
}?></table>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It appears that others have also had the same problem. I still don't know the solution, but one commonality appears to be Virtuemart version 1.1.9 stable. Any ideas?
[Link to Virtuemart Forum](http://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=95217.0)

Answer (score 0):

The change is in **components/com_virtuemart/themes/"yourtemplate"/templates/common/productsnapshot.tpl.php**

Under `<!-- The product name DIV. -->`

I changed the div style code to this:

```
<div style="height:35px; float:left; width: 100%;line-height:14px;">
```

Under `<!-- The product image DIV. -->`

I change the div style code to this:

```
<div style="width: 100%;float:left">
```

And it took away all of the unnecessary white space